# Custom Module overlaps magento default theme

Tags: magento-2.1, module, custom

I have a Sliding contact us module.This module overlaps with the navigation menu of default magento luma theme. How do i fix this issue?

Comment: you can copy luma theme template and override it into your theme.

Comment: Am also working under the same luma theme. The thing is its working fine with my system but not with the tester after pulling the code from bitbucket.